# How to fix my numberOfDigits function

Tags: performance, algorithm, vba, math, optimization

Came across some code where the number of digits was being determined by casting the number to a string then using a len().

```
Function numOfDigits_len(n As Long) As Long
    numOfDigits_len = Len(Str(n)) - 1
End Function
```

Now although this works I knew it would be slow compared to any method that didn't use strings, so I wrote one that uses log().

```
Function numOfDigits_log(n As Long) As Long
    numOfDigits_log = Int(Log(n) / Log(10)) + 1
End Function
```

Cut run time by 1/2 which was great but there was something weird happening in a specific case.

```
  n     numOfDigits_log(n)
=====  ====================
 999            3
1000            3
1001            4
```

It would not handle `1000` properly.  I figured it is because of floating point and rounding issues.

```
Function numOfDigits_loop(ByVal n As Long) As Long
    Do Until n = 0
        n = n \ 10
        numOfDigits_loop = numOfDigits_loop + 1
    Loop
End Function
```

Wrote this which turned out to be ~10% slower as numbers got larger than 10^6 and seems to become slowly larger as n gets bigger.  Which is fine if I was being pragmatic but I would like to find something more ideal.

Now my question is, is there a way to use the log() method accurately.  I could do something like

```
Function numOfDigits_log(n As Long) As Long
    numOfDigits_log = Int(Log(n) / Log(10) + 0.000000001) + 1
End Function
```

But it seems very "hacky".  Is there a nicer way that's faster or as fast as the log() method?
 Note: I realize this kind of optimization is pointless in a lot of cases but now that I've come across this I would like to "fix" it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered this before, but I couldn't find it, so here's the basics:

```
int i = ... some number >= 0 ...
int n = 1;
if (i >= 100000000){i /= 100000000; n += 8;}
if (i >= 10000){i /= 10000; n += 4;}
if (i >= 100){i /= 100; n += 2;}
if (i >= 10){i /= 10; n += 1;}
```

That's in C, but you get the idea.

Comment: This is a great solution, basically ~30-35% faster than the log() method.

Answer (score 1):

A while loop guarantees correctness, i.e. it doesn't use any floating point calculations

```
int numDigits = 0;
while(num != 0) {
    num /= 10;
    numDigits++;
}
```

You can also speed this up by using a larger divisor

```
int numDigits = 0;
if(num >= 100000 || num <= -100000) {
    int prevNum;
    while(num != 0) {
        prevNum = num;
        num /= 100000;
        numDigits += 5;
    }
    num = prevNum;
    numDigits -= 5;
}
while(num != 0) {
    num /= 10;
    numDigits++;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I implemented it incorrectly but my results were that its slower than just a straight loop.

Answer (score 0):

You'll love this.

We live in a base 10 number system!  That means all you have to do is ROUND UP.

the length of some number ALWAYS = `ceiling (log n)`.   So for instance: 7456412 (a 7-digit number).  Log (7456412) = 6.8...round up and you have 7.  log (9999) = 3.9999.  Round up and it's 4.

The special case is when you DON'T have to round, or when you have some power of 10.  For instance: log(1000) = 3.  if you can detect when you have a power of 10, add one to the log result and you win!

the way you could do this detection is something like

```
double log10;
int clog10;
int length;

log10 = (Log(n) / Log(10)); // can also use a private static final long hardcoded for Log(10)
clog10 = ceiling(log10);
if (Int(log10) == clog10)
  length = clog10 + 1;
else
  length = clog10;
```

Comment: also, for the record, log(10) = 1, so there's no point in dividing by it.

Comment: I'd be surprised if VBA used base 10 for `log`. Every programming language I know uses - as it should - the natural logarithm, that is, base `e = 2.71828...`.

Comment: Several problems: 1. log in OP's post is likely log2; 2. what if floating point error makes log(10) = 1.00000000001 (maybe not, need proof)? 3. How do you detect if a number is 10^k instantly?

Comment: oh.  well thats a little silly.  carry on with the dividing then.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei: 1: already addressed by others, and I will grant them that.  2: use another program and hardcode log(10) if it becomes an issue.  3: assuming #2 is not a problem, my code checks that.